# ¿Es posible crear etiquetas como inputs, textarea, button, etc... solo desde javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Supongamos que tenemos un formulario pequeño con etiquetas input:

```
<form action="registrardatos.php" method="post">
  Ingrese el nombre del archivo:
  <input type="text" name="nombre" size="20">
  <br>
  <input type="file" name="myFile">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" name="Enviar">
```

y que tenemos un botón así:

```
<button onclick="agregarelemento()">Añadir</button>
```

En este caso me gustaría saber si existe una forma de replicar las etiquetas `input`(o cualquier otra etiqueta) dentro del mismo formulario, con el fin de añadir mas archivos y su nombre de forma indefinida, esto sin necesidad de crear los formularios sin necesidad de ponerlos ocultos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function AddElement() {
  try {
    const containerElement = document.createElement("DIV");

    const labelFileName = document.createElement("LABEL");
    labelFileName.innerText = "File Name";

    const inputFileName = document.createElement("INPUT");
    inputFileName.setAttribute("type", "text");
    inputFileName.setAttribute("name", "fileName");
    inputFileName.setAttribute("size", "20");
    labelFileName.appendChild(inputFileName);
    containerElement.appendChild(labelFileName);

    const inputFile = document.createElement("INPUT");
    inputFile.setAttribute("type", "file");
    inputFile.setAttribute("name", "myFile");
    containerElement.appendChild(inputFile);

    document.getElementById("boxFile").appendChild(containerElement);

  } catch (error) {
    console.error("AddElement =>", error);
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="boxFile">
    <div>
      <label> File Name<input type="text" name="fileName" size="20"></label>
      <input type="file" name="myFile">
    </div>

  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Send">
</div>
<button onclick="AddElement()">Add</button>
```

Si, puedes crear elementos dinámicos si lo deseas con las diferentes etiquetas que existen en `Html`, en el ejemplo mencionó cómo utilizar el `document.createElement` y el `containerElement.appendChild` para crear nodos y insertarlos en las diferentes etiquetas.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!